# Use of Building names in Fiction

Tags: fiction, legal, copyright

I know that using branded companies names is a no no if shown in a negative light, but what is the "legal" Stance on Buildings that get damaged/blown up/fist fight etc..?

as they are owned by a company does the same rule apply as if you were negatively portraying a company?

For instance could I say that a disgruntled employee blows up Grand Central Station in NYC

thank you in advance

Comment: The problem is not that you use a building, but possibly some company resides in that building that you throw a bad light on. For example, if you write a story about a disgruntled employee blowing up the Googleplex, the problem will not be that it is that builing, but that that building belongs to Google and you are implying that Google has bad working conditions and hires emotionally unstable persons capable of commiting such a crime. Grand Central Station and other public buildings will not be a problem.

Comment: As soon as you have illustrations showing an existing building, you need a property release by the owner (if you have to step on their grounds to take the photo), architect (because he owns the copyright to his design) and/or residents (whose name or logo are visible on the building).

Comment: Ok, so I am going to rename the shops that currently reside in the building anyway,but as it is a public building I am ok to use it? right?

Comment: There are many examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22grand+central+station%22+%22fiction%22 or https://www.google.de/search?q=%22grand+central+station%22+%22fiction%22&tbm=bks

Comment: @user1731335; please note that we are not lawyers. If you are concerned about this you should ask a lawyer before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I do understand and appreciate that you are not lawyers.